# программно вызвать ACTION_MOVE на элемент, andorid

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня есть экран и джостик, если человек нажал на левую половину экрана, то там появляется джостик, но мне нужно чтобы при дальнейших манипуляция, таких как движение пальца по экрану, не отпуская его, вызывался соответствующий event у джостика, а не у игровго экрана.

Код onTouch

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.joystickField: // нажатие на джостик
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                joystickX = joystick.getWidth() / 2;
                joystickY = joystick.getHeight() / 2;
                moveJoystick(joystickMove, joystick, event, (float) gameView.goAngle);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                gameView.go = true;
                gameView.goAngle = (float) (Math.atan2(joystickY - event.getY(), event.getX() - joystickX)) * (-1);
                moveJoystick(joystickMove, joystick, event, (float) gameView.goAngle);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                gameView.go = false;
                joystickMove.setX(joystick.getX() + joystick.getWidth() / 2 - joystickMove.getWidth() / 2);
                joystickMove.setY(joystick.getY() + joystick.getHeight() / 2 - joystickMove.getHeight() / 2);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.gameLayout:
            if (MainActivity.getControlFire() == 1) { // стрельба нажатием на экран
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    gameView.startFire(event.getX(), event.getY());
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    gameView.stopFire();
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                    gameView.startFire(event.getX(), event.getY());
            } else if (MainActivity.getControlFire() == 0) { // стрельба дджостиком
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (event.getX() < gameLayout.getWidth() / 2) { // нажатие на часть экрана для перемещения игрока (левая половина)
                        joystick.setX(event.getX() - joystick.getWidth() / 2);
                        joystick.setY(event.getY() - joystick.getHeight() / 2);
                        joystickMove.setX(joystick.getX() + joystick.getWidth() / 2 - joystickMove.getWidth() / 2);
                        joystickMove.setY(joystick.getY() + joystick.getHeight() / 2 - joystickMove.getHeight() / 2);
                        joystickX = event.getX();
                        joystickY = event.getY();
                        // пробую всякое
                        MotionEvent motionEvent = event; //MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, joystickX, joystickY, 1);
                        motionEvent.setLocation(joystick.getX() + joystick.getWidth() / 2, joystick.getY() + joystick.getHeight() / 2);
                        motionEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                        motionEvent.setEdgeFlags(1);
                        //motionEvent.offsetLocation(joystick.getX() + joystick.getWidth() / 2, joystick.getY() + joystick.getHeight() / 2);
                        onTouch(findViewById(R.id.joystickField), motionEvent);
                        //long
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Мне по идее нужно как то правильно вызвать onTouch с ивентом ACTION_MOVE, есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о "правильном вызове onTouch", то делается это примерно так

```
MotionEvent mi = MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 100, 100, 0);
view.dispatchTouchEvent(mi);
```

либо можно взять объект `MotionEvent` после реального ACTION_MOVE и через `mi.setLocation(x,y)` поменять, я так понимаю, координату х.

Этот метод довольно грязен, я бы не советовал им пользоваться. А для более дельного совета я не совсем понял, что требуется.

Comment: я так и делал, либо не правильно вас понял, но я записывал все в логи все заходы при нажатии, движении и отпускании, по джостику. И когда я просто по нему нажимаю, там много раз вызывается ACTION_MOVE, а при вызове его программно он вызывется всего один раз, возможно я изъяснился не правильно и мне нужно именно нажатие обработать или грубо говоря перекинуть его с одного элемента на другой. В 2-х словах: человек нажал на экран, там появился джостик (ImageView) и с помощью него можно управлять персонажем

Comment: Тогда может быть есть смысл сделать два обработчика onTouch для каждой части экрана и тогда уже дублировать ивенты в другой слушатель? По крайней мере будет проще разобраться, что происходит и откуда.

Comment: я так и делал сначала, но если пользователь будет нажимать на левую часть экрана и тянуть до правой части, то он сбросится, так как ивент только на левую часть экрана. Либо так, либо не правильно вас понял

Comment: И скорее всего это придётся пилить через множественные касания?